# Webservice Exception while pushing the parent records, Mulesoft webservice consumer error while pushing the records

Tags: web-services, mule-component

I am getting the exception when trying to consume the soap webservice in Mulesoft

> Message: Fault occurred while processing Message payload is of type:
>   NullPayload Type: org.mule.module.ws.consumer.SoapFaultException
>
> Code: MULE_ERROR--2 Payload: {NullPayload} Exception stack is:
>   1.Fault occurred while processing.. Message payload is of type:NullPayload   (org.mule.module.ws.consumer.SoapFaultException)
>   org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer$1:196 Root Exception stack
>   trace: org.mule.module.ws.consumer.SoapFaultException: Fault occurred
>   while processing.. Message payload is of type: NullPayload at
>   org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer$1.processNext(WSConsumer.java:196)
>   Root Exception stack trace:
>   org.mule.module.ws.consumer.SoapFaultException:Fault occurred while
>   processing.. Message payload is of type: NullPayload at
>   org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer$1.processNext(WSConsumer.java:196)
>   org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor
>   org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute or`enter
>   code here`g.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext
>   org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute
>   org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.exe
>   org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute
>   org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute
>   org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer.process
>   org.mule.routing.AbstractUntilSuccessfulProcessingStrategy.processEvent
>   org.mule.routing.SynchronousUntilSuccessfulProcessingStrategy.rout
>   org.mule.routing.UntilSuccessful.route
>   org.mule.routing.outbound.AbstractOutboundRouter$1.process
>   org.mule.routing.outbound.AbstractOutboundRouter$1.proces
>   org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute
>   org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute
>   org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute
>   org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute
>   org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute
>   org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext
>   org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute
>   org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.exe
>   org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute
>   org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute
>   org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer.process
>   org.mule.routing.AbstractUntilSuccessfulProcessingStrategy.processEvent

Comment: Error is clear `NullPayload`, add more details.

Comment: Do you have a sample request payload that is causing the exception? Based on the error, I would surmise it's because the payload being sent in the request is missing. Also, when asking questions, consider explaining research done more thoroughly, as well doing what you can to help others repro the problem if possible. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not passing the payload to the WS consumer. WS consumer need a Paylaod to invoke your external service. Could you please share your config xml file so that we can validate and help you on this.